# usando CAST no INNER

Tags: c#, sql, inner

Bom dia
estou tentando fazer um join mas da erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 string Query = "Select rec.chvbfj, rec.doc, vndB.chvvnd, vndB.chvps, ps.chvps, ps.Dsc " +
               "From (( " +
               "rec " +
               "inner join vndB " +
               "on vndB.chvvnda = cast(rec.doc as int)) " +
               "inner join ps " +
               "on ps.chvps = vndB.chvps)";
```

da o erro:

> Falha de IErrorInfo.GetDescription com E_FAIL(0x80004005).'

rec.chvbfj numero
rec.doc texto
vndB.chvvnda numero
vndB.chvps numero
ps.chvps numero
ps.Dsc texto

Vou listar rec.chvbfj (3), resultado seria 3(3,4,5), formato texto, procuro na tabela vndB.chvnda(3,4,5), formato numerico, do campo chvps o resultado tem que sair da tabela ps campo Dsc o nome.

Comment: Tente remover os parenteses: Os dois depois do `From`, o segundo depois do `cast`, e o que está no fim da query e tente novamente.

Comment: Tente utilizar ou a função CInt ou a CStr do Microsoft Access.

Comment: Antes de usar verifique se é seu caso: [Suporte da Microsoft Hotfix E_FAIL(0x80004005)](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/921292/fix-you-may-receive-a-0x80004005-e-fail-error-message-when-you-use-a-r)

Answer (score 0):

Com base no que você forneceu consegui fazer algo que talvez você precise!
obs: ignore as tabelas temporária!

```
declare @rec table(chvbfj int, doc varchar(20))
insert into @rec values(1,'1')
insert into @rec values(2,'2')
insert into @rec values(3,'3')
insert into @rec values(3,'4')
insert into @rec values(3,'5')
insert into @rec values(4,'6')

declare @vndB table(chvvnda int, chvps int)
insert into @vndB values(3,1)
insert into @vndB values(4,1)
insert into @vndB values(5,2)

declare @ps table(chvps int, Descc text)
insert into @ps values(1,'escova')
insert into @ps values(1,'escova')
insert into @ps values(2,'lixa')

declare @rec_temp table(chvbfj int, doc int)
insert into @rec_temp(chvbfj,doc)
select * from @rec where doc in (3,4,5)


Select a.chvbfj, a.doc, b.chvvnda, b.chvps, c.chvps, c.Descc
               From 
               @rec_temp A
               inner join @vndB B
               on b.chvvnda = a.doc
               inner join @ps C
               on c.chvps = b.chvps
```